# Maximum and Minimum Values on an Interval

Tags: calculus

What is the minimum and maximum values respectively of the function $f(x) = 5x^3 - 2x^2 + a$ on the interval $(-2,2)$.

The answer among choices is $(-47,33)$,
though there are other choices like
$(-4,4)$, $(0.95,1)$, and $(0, 0.27)$.

I assume "a" is constant. So i try getting derivative and summing it to zero gives me: 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} 5x^3 -2x^2 + a = x(15x-4) \Rightarrow 0 = x(15x-4)
$$

One root is zero, and the other is $15/4$. Is the problem set in some way wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: There's a problem with the question.

Comment: Yes, the maximum and minimum values are certainly going to depend on $a$.

Comment: $ \ 15x \ - \ 4 \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ \frac{15}{4} \ $ _!?_  You will find that the two local extrema are _very_ close to one another and _cannot_ be the absolute extrema on the interval $ \ [ -2 , 2 ] \ $ .  (The interval shouldn't be _open_ , should it? If it is, there aren't any absolute extrema, but then none of the choices you list work either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your calculations and the extreme value theorem, we know the maximum and minimum on $[-2,2]$ will occur at $-2$, $0$, $4/15$, or $2$. Plugging those values in, we get
$$ -48+a,\quad a,\quad -.047+a,\quad 32+a $$
so clearly the answer is $(-48+a,32+a)$. Of the options you listed, only $(-47,33)$ has this form.

Note: these values correspond to the endpoint of the interval, which based on the original statement of the question, are not actually included. I assume this is a typo, because the maximum and minimum values will not be attained if the interval does not contain its endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum and minimum will depend on $a$, but their difference will not.  You know the max and min come either at the roots of the derivative or at the ends of the interval.  Note that $15/4$ is outside your interval, but $4/15$ is inside.  So set $a=0$ as it will not matter for this and evaluate the function at those three points.  The difference between the max and min should correspond to one of your choices.  If you want, you can find the value of $a$ that makes the max and min be correct.